# React Redux Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am sure if I follow the rules but I have this error on this function

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

in this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getAll } from './../../services/events/api';
import EventsList from '../../containers/EventsList';
import IEvent from './../../services/events/models/IEvent';
import Loading from './../../components/Loading';
import Error from './../../components/Error';
const EventList = () => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState<Array<IEvent>>([]);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetch = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const events: Array<IEvent> = await getAll();
      setEvents(events);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {error ? (
        <Error title="Sorry" subtitle="Error loading events" />
      ) : isLoading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <EventsList events={events} />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default EventList;
```

where is the error? for Invalid hook call

Comment: are you trying to execute your function component like `EventList ()`?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon just call this like component <EventList /> and work

Comment: exactly that, the error should only show if you are trying to execute the Component as a function but if you are rendering the component either through jsx or using `createElement` there should be no error

Comment: ok I understand now